# Can't get Retrofit 2 to send globally-set headers with Dagger 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, okhttp

I've been wanting to adopt Dagger 2 in conjugation with Retrofit 2. All seems to work nicely except for `GET` requests; they doesn't seem to have any headers attached with them.

Below is my `NetworkModule` which provides all networking-related dependencies for the whole app (note the `@ForApplication` scope annotation sprinkled there):

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    // …

    @ForApplication
    @Provides
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttp(
            HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor,
            @Named(PREFERENCE_CUR_LOGIN_SESSION) Preference<LoginSession> loginSessionPreference,
            DeviceCredentials deviceCredentials
    ) {
        final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
        builder.addNetworkInterceptor(chain -> {
            if (loginSessionPreference.isSet()) {
                return chain.proceed(
                        chain.request().newBuilder()
                                .addHeader("token", loginSessionPreference.get().getTokenId())
                                .addHeader("device-id", deviceCredentials.getDeviceId())
                                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                .build()
                );
            } else {
                return chain.proceed(
                        chain.request().newBuilder().build()
                );
            }
        });
        return builder.build();
    }

    @ForApplication
    @Provides
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient client) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/1.0/")
                .client(client)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }

    @ForApplication
    @Provides
    XxxApi provideApi(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(XxxApi.class);
    }
}
```

This module is supplied as a dependency for my `ApplicationComponent` (among other modules):

```
@ForApplication
@Component(
        modules = {
                ApplicationModule.class,
                RuntimeModule.class,
                DateFormatModule.class,
                PreferenceModule.class,
                NetworkModule.class
        }
)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    // …
}
```

I've ran a debug session and confirmed that `loginSessionPreference.isSet()` is evaluated as `true` but nevertheless my request still showed up without any headers:

```
11-16 16:55:22.748 21747-22569/xxx.xxx.xxx D/OkHttp: --> GET http://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/1.0/public/get-all-data/site http/1.1
11-16 16:55:22.748 21747-22569/xxx.xxx.xxx D/OkHttp: --> END GET
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: take a look from here you better understand https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sampleapp/api/NetModule.java

Comment: @Raghunandan, isn't that what `addNetworkInterceptor` already does? Well, not exactly the method, but the `Interceptor` that passed-in.

Comment: I saw it now. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Use .addInterceptor instead of .addNetworkInterceptor()

Answer (score 0):

First of all use *addInterceptor()* like Alex Shutov suggested.

Secondly, ensure in debug mode that methods *addHeader()* are called.
If you use the same *Retrofit* instance (same injection) it could not be used because *loginSessionPreference.isSet()* always returns false.

Your method *provideOkHttp()* is called while *OkHttpClient* is necessary to provide *Retrofit* instance. Method *provideOkHttp()* requires *Preference* and it is injected while object *OkHttpClient* is created. You can treat it as a final variable (compiler even makes it final I think).

Please delete *loginSessionPreference* logic and hardcode some headers - it will gonna tell us if it is the issue.

In my opinion you will need to change this architecture a little.